# How to correctly send messages daily in telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have a problem using the job_queue and run daily messages in my telegram bot. I have already read and tried every answer I have found in stack overflow and online, but somehow nothing works and I don't know what's wrong.
I want to send a message daily, but only after the /start command, and I want to shut down the bot and the scheduled messages with the /stop command. I am using version 13.5. Here's the code at the moment:

```
import logging, os, random, sys, random, datetime
from telegram import ParseMode, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

...

def callback_daily(context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(
        text="DAILY TEXT",
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )

def start_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):   

    context.bot.run_daily(callback_daily, 
        days=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),
        time=datetime.time(hour=20, minute=00, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Rome")),
        context=update.message.chat_id
    )
    
    update.message.reply_text(
        "STARTED"
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.info("### Starting Bot ###")

    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(CommandHandler("error", error_handler))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_handler, pass_job_queue=True))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_handler))
    
    ...

    run(updater)
    logger.info("### Bot Started ###")
```

What I get at the moment is:

```
 AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'run_daily'
```

I have tried also many other things found here in Stackoveflow, so many that I don't even remember them, and somehow every answer shows a different method to run scheduled message (and not even one works at the moment).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nor have you specified what `context` is, nor have you showed any of the relevant modules / classes. Also, the error basically states that the class / module you're using doesn't have a `run_daily` function, meaning that the code you took this from / module documentation probably uses another custom class for the `Bot`.

Comment: I have added some more info. I actually don't know much more. What is context? I dunno, I just followed a guide on how to develop a telegram bot and it's working good, but the job queue and scheduled messages.

Comment: If you need to schedule you can use cron-job with another script. but you need to insert started users user_id  to db ot file. then create a new script for send messages to all the users in that db or file, then run it is as a cron-job [cron-job](https://cron-job.org/)